# How to output query value only once?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfquery, cfloop

I have query that returns four columns. One of the columns can have the same value for multiple records. I would like to output that value only once. Here is example of the data:

```
Rec ID  Name   Color  Year
45      Nick   Green  2018
34      Mike   Red    2018
37      Nick   Blue   2019
44      John   Pink   2019
23      Jimmy  Orange 2019
```

I uses this code to output the values:

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop query="myQuery">
     <cfif fiscal_year gt 1991>
        <tr>    
            <td colspan="4"><a href="new_page.cfm?year=#year#>View All</a></td>
        </tr>
     </cfif>
     <tr>
        <td>#rec_id#</td>
        <td>#name#</td>
        <td>#color#</td>
        <td>#year#</td>
     </tr>
   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

My output looks like this:

```
View All
45      Nick   Green  2018
View All
34      Mike   Red    2018
View All
37      Nick   Blue   2019
View All
44      John   Pink   2019
View All
23      Jimmy  Orange 2019
```

Instead I would like my output too look like this:

```
View All
45      Nick   Green  2018
34      Mike   Red    2018
View All
37      Nick   Blue   2019
44      John   Pink   2019
23      Jimmy  Orange 2019
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be on the query side, doing a group by function. Otherwise you have to manipulate the dataset and do a nested loop

Comment: `<cfoutput query="myQuery" group="DesiredColumn">`

Comment: ... one often overlooked requirement of "grouped" cfoutput's or cfloop's is that the query data must *already* be sorted by the proper columns, for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<cfoutput>` tag has a `group` attribute that allows you to group your query data by a column. You can nest the grouped data in another `<cfoutput>` tag and even group by multiple columns. It should look something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="myQuery" group="year">
    <cfif fiscal_year gt 1991>
        <tr>    
            <td colspan="4"><a href="new_page.cfm?year=#year#">View All</a></td>
        </tr>
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>
    <tr>
        <td>#rec_id#</td>
        <td>#name#</td>
        <td>#color#</td>
        <td>#year#</td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Note, if you're grouping by "year", the query data MUST be sorted by that column first, or you won't get the expected results. See [cfoutput documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfoutput.html): *`group` = Query column to use to group sets of records. Eliminates adjacent duplicate rows **when data is sorted** ....*